# Dropbox syncing never finishes

Tags: 12.04, dropbox

When I connect to Dropbox, it starts syncing the files, but never finishes. "dropbox status" says:   "Uploading 802 files...  Downloading file list..." and this remains like this forever. I tried "dropbox stop" and "dropbox start" but it didn't work. How can I make my Dropbox sync again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am also getting the same error and it solved by updating the drop box. I upgraded it with a latest version. from terminal.

Comment: Thanks, I used this link: https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx and the problem was solved. The only problem is that the changes I made to my Dropbox folder before the install, got mixed up with changes I made from other computers..